# nodejs: how to get intermediate hash values

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, sha256

I want to secure the content of a sequential file using a sha256 hash value.
As the file has to be extended during runtime, a hash calculation is required upon each append/extension.
What I would like to have is a perpetual hash object, being updated with the appended data only and allowing to retrieve intermediate results.

As the implementation should be done in nodejs, the javascript code could look like this:

```
const fs = require('fs'), crypto = require('crypto')
var hashPerp = crypto.createHash('sha256')

var data = 'record 1'
fs.writeFileSync('mylist.dat', data)
hashPerp.update(data)
var hashInter = CLONE(hashPerp)
console.log(hashInter.digest('base64'))

data = 'record 2'
fs.appendFileSync('mylist.dat', data)
hashPerp.update(data)
hashInter = CLONE(hashPerp)
console.log(hashInter.digest('base64'))

...
```

I did not find an appropriate object CLONE() function, and cloning the hash object with its internal buffers also may not be the only way to solve the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: so, after the append, do you wish to hash 'record1record2' which would be contents of the file, or only 'record2' ?

Comment: I don't think you can interact with the hash function like that, telling it something like: `look, I already have this piece calculated for you, so you don't have to! Please take it!`. This is not how security works. Also, having a single extra character into a file results into a totally different hash, so the pre-calculated hash is useless.

Comment: @Dhananjai Pai: as result I would need the hash over the whole file, i.e. 'record 1record 2'

Comment: @AdrianPop: if you look into a sha256 sourcecode, actually an array of 8 long integer fields is updated with 64 byte (octet) blocks of input data. digest() or finalize() then derives the final 32 byte result. The bad thing is, that digest() destroys the working buffers, you cannot proceed updating. So I assume, that it could be done with an own implementation of sha256. But I would like to avoid doing this in slow javascript, and also it would require deeper knowledge of the algorithm.

Comment: I think the algorithm destroys the buffers for a reason :)

Comment: Yes, you can take a SHA-256 implementation and take it apart. Of course, you can only calculate the hash result after padding and such. So you need to cache the result of the block *right before the last block(s)* with the padding & length are calculated as well as any data that is hashed in that last or first-to-last block. I haven't seen any pre-made solutions though, so you will probably have to do this yourself.

Comment: @Maarten: thank you for your comment. It helps me, that you don't know a solution, as I was surprised not finding any approach. I think, I will have a look into SJCL sha256.js (seems to be the fastest javascript implementation).

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking too complicated: in my case (to express the content of a file) a "SHA" -Secure Hash Algorithm - actually is NOT required, a simple hash function can do the job. So, CRC32 will be used, which allows consecutive addition of bytes.